# Drupal 7 Search API, Elasticsearch Connector, Aggregation/Facets

Tags: search, elasticsearch, drupal-7, drupal-modules, aggregation

I am using [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Elasticsearch Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/elasticsearch_connector) in my Drupal 7 site. I have hosted the elasticsearch in AWS. Searching works perfectly without any issues. But I would like to add the facetapi filters like in the [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/aggregation) search result page.

[image]

It seems like facetapi is removed from elasticsearch and added the support for aggregation.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_facets_have_been_removed

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-aggregations.html

But even the aggregation is not fully supported.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2643822

https://www.drupal.org/node/2503343

Any suggestion or idea how can I achieve this? Is there any other way or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

yeah. 
use 
https://www.drupal.org/project/elasticsearch_connector

and use the elasticsearch version 1.x. 
Elasticsearch 2.x is in Dev.

Comment: Can you please elaborate This doesn't answer the question

Comment: the drupal elasticsearch connector has no stable support for ES2 yet. 
The only way to get a working facet search with elasticsearch on drupal  is to use ES Version 1.